# Amazon S3 SignatureDoesNotMatch error with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload files to Amazon S3 using a backend with nodejs and express. The problem is that when I try to upload the file I get the following error.

```
SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

The policy of the IAM User have permissions to upload files to the bucket, and keys of the user are well.

Here you have the configuration of s3 and the function I use to upload files:

```js
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    region: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_REGION,
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY
}) 

export const uploadFileS3 = (file) => {

    const uploadParams = {
        Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
        Body: file.data,
        Key: file.name
    };

    return s3.upload(uploadParams).promise()
}
```

And here is the express controller which I'm using to try to upload files:

```js
routerProgress.post("/upload-progress", verifyJWT, async (req, res) => {
    const { file1 } = req.files;
    const res = await uploadFileS3(file1);
    console.log(res);
}
```

If anyone know what's going wrong please I would be very grateful with him. I've lost so many hours with that.

Comment: Did you get the solution? i am also facing same error

Answer (score 2):

There may be several reasons for the error.

Check the following and apply, still the error goes away.

1. Use a signature version

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    region: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_REGION,
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
    signatureVersion: 'v4'
})
```

2. Check for spaces before and after the AWS_SECRET_KEY
3. If the key contains special characters, then use backslashes for them.
4. If the file name contains UTF8 characters, then encode.